# python-xarray: open_dataarray Segmentation fault on HPC

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I'm struggling to understand why reading in a NetCDF file using [`open_dataarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataarray.html) in the HPC I use produces a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. However, when I read in the file using [`open_dataarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataarray.html) on my Mac it works fine.

From looking into this further it is the NPac file (the sub-section) which I created which seems to have issues. Here is the steps I took to generate the file:

- WaveWatchIII outputs a file
- Extract July: `$ncks -d time,0,30 in.nc out.nc` Can open out.nc in HPC
- Extract variable: `$ncks -v hs in.nc out.nc` Can open out.nc in HPC
- Extract domain: `$ncks -d longitude,100.0,290.0 -d latitude,0.0,65.0 in.nc out.nc` Cannot open out.nc on HPC but can open out.nc on Mac.

This is the first time i've seen this issue and I believe it is due to properties of the domain of the NetCDF file. I'm guessing it may have something to do with versions as well? I do most of the heavy lifting on the HPC and use my Mac for testing and understanding so it would be nice to get this working on the HPC.

The NetCDF file can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/raybellwaves/test/blob/master/ww3.Hs.July.NPac.nc)

```
ncdump -h ww3.Hs.July.NPac.nc
netcdf ww3.Hs.July.NPac {
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (31 currently)
    latitude = 66 ;
    longitude = 191 ;
variables:
    short hs(time, latitude, longitude) ;
            hs:long_name = "significant height of wind and swell waves" ;
            hs:standard_name = "sea_surface_wave_significant_height" ;
            hs:globwave_name = "significant_wave_height" ;
            hs:units = "m" ;
            hs:_FillValue = -32767s ;
            hs:scale_factor = 0.002f ;
            hs:add_offset = 0.f ;
            hs:valid_min = 0 ;
            hs:valid_max = 32000 ;
    float latitude(latitude) ;
            latitude:units = "degree_north" ;
            latitude:long_name = "latitude" ;
            latitude:standard_name = "latitude" ;
            latitude:valid_min = -90.f ;
            latitude:valid_max = 90.f ;
            latitude:axis = "Y" ;
    float longitude(longitude) ;
            longitude:units = "degree_east" ;
            longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;
            longitude:standard_name = "longitude" ;
            longitude:valid_min = -180.f ;
            longitude:valid_max = 180.f ;
            longitude:axis = "X" ;
    double time(time) ;
            time:long_name = "julian day (UT)" ;
            time:standard_name = "time" ;
            time:units = "days since 1850-01-01T00:00:00Z" ;
            time:conventions = "relative julian days with decimal part (as parts of the day )" ;
            time:axis = "T" ;

// global attributes:
            :WAVEWATCH_III_version_number = "4.18b" ;
            :WAVEWATCH_III_switches = "NC4 F90 NOGRB NOPA LRB4 SHRD PR3 UQ FLX0 LN1 ST4 STAB0 NL1 BT1 DB1 MLIM TR0 BS0 IC0 REF0 XX0 WNT1 WNX1 CRT1 CRX1 O0 O1 O2 O3 O4 O5 O6 O7 O11 O14 TRKNC" ;
            :SDS4\ namelist\ parameter\ WHITECAPWIDTH = 0.3f ;
            :product_name = "ww3.199307.nc" ;
            :area = "Indian Ocean Pacfic 1 degree" ;
            :latitude_resolution = "   1.0000000" ;
            :longitude_resolution = "   1.0000000" ;
            :southernmost_latitude = "-70.0000000" ;
            :northernmost_latitude = "65.0000000" ;
            :westernmost_longitude = "20.0000000" ;
            :easternmost_longitude = "295.0000000" ;
            :minimum_altitude = "-12000 m" ;
            :maximum_altitude = "9000 m" ;
            :altitude_resolution = "n/a" ;
            :start_date = "1993-07-01T00:00:00Z" ;
            :stop_date = "1993-07-31T00:00:00Z" ;
            :history = "Sat Dec  2 17:53:06 2017: ncks -O -d longitude,100.0,290.0 -d latitude,0.0,65.0 /projects/rsmas/kirtman/rxb826/WW3exps/IO_Pac_CCSM4/CCSM4_19930701_19940630_1a1/work/ww3.Hs.July.nc /projects/rsmas/kirtman/rxb826/WW3exps/IO_Pac_CCSM4/CCSM4_19930701_19940630_1a1/work/ww3.Hs.July.NPac.nc\nSat Dec  2 17:53:06 2017: ncks -O -v hs /projects/rsmas/kirtman/rxb826/WW3exps/IO_Pac_CCSM4/CCSM4_19930701_19940630_1a1/work/ww3.July.nc /projects/rsmas/kirtman/rxb826/WW3exps/IO_Pac_CCSM4/CCSM4_19930701_19940630_1a1/work/ww3.Hs.July.nc\nSat Dec  2 17:53:05 2017: ncks -O -d time,0,30 /projects/rsmas/kirtman/rxb826/WW3exps/IO_Pac_CCSM4/CCSM4_19930701_19940630_1a1/work/ww3.19930701_19940630.nc /projects/rsmas/kirtman/rxb826/WW3exps/IO_Pac_CCSM4/CCSM4_19930701_19940630_1a1/work/ww3.July.nc\nFri Nov  4 13:50:57 2016: ncrcat -O -o tmp.nc ww3.199307.nc ww3.199308.nc ww3.199309.nc ww3.199310.nc ww3.199311.nc ww3.199312.nc ww3.199401.nc ww3.199402.nc ww3.199403.nc ww3.199404.nc ww3.199405.nc ww3.199406.nc" ;
            :nco_openmp_thread_number = 1 ;
            :NCO = "4.3.7" ;
```

On the HPC:

```
$ nc-config --version
netCDF 4.2.1.1

>>> xr.show_versions()
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.3.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: en_US.UTF-8

xarray: 0.10.0
pandas: 0.20.2
numpy: 1.13.1
scipy: 0.19.1
netCDF4: 1.2.4
h5netcdf: None
Nio: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
cyordereddict: None
dask: 0.16.0
matplotlib: 2.0.2
cartopy: 0.15.1
seaborn: None
setuptools: 27.2.0
pip: 9.0.1
conda: 4.3.30
pytest: None
IPython: None
sphinx: None

>>> xr.open_dataarray('ww3.Hs.July.NPac.nc')
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

On my Mac:

```
$ nc-config --version
netCDF 4.4.1

xr.show_versions()
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.3.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 17.2.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: en_US.UTF-8

xarray: 0.10.0
pandas: 0.20.1
numpy: 1.12.1
scipy: 1.0.0
netCDF4: 1.2.4
h5netcdf: None
Nio: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
cyordereddict: None
dask: 0.16.0
matplotlib: 2.1.0
cartopy: 0.15.1
seaborn: 0.8.1
setuptools: 36.2.7
pip: 9.0.1
conda: 4.3.29
pytest: 3.2.0
IPython: 6.2.1
sphinx: 1.5.6

In [10]:xr.open_dataarray('ww3.Hs.July.NPac.nc')
Out[10]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'hs' (time: 31, latitude: 66, longitude: 191)>
[390786 values with dtype=float64]
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 ...
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 100.0 101.0 102.0 103.0 104.0 105.0 106.0 ...
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2013-07-01 2013-07-02 2013-07-03 ...
Attributes:
    long_name:      significant height of wind and swell waves
    standard_name:  sea_surface_wave_significant_height
    globwave_name:  significant_wave_height
    units:          m
    valid_min:      0
    valid_max:      32000
```

Comment: Also check netcdf library version using `nc-config --version` ?

Comment: Thanks. It's an older version on the HPC. I could try upgrading it and seeing if it impacts. I thought `nc-config` is independent of xarray though?

Comment: True, `xarray` should have its own statically linked netcdf lib. But the one revealed by `nc-config` is likely to be the same once that `ncks` is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies. It looks like my `ncks` command wasn't completing property. Nothing to do with `xarray` just strange my Mac wasn't throwing up an error. Stranger still that giving out.nc a different file name seems to fix it

```
$ncks -O -d longitude,100.0,290.0 -d latitude,0.0,65.0 ww3.Hs.July.nc ww3.Hs.July.NPac.nc
$python
>>>import xarray as xr
>>>xr.open_dataarray('ww3.Hs.July.NPac.nc')
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ncks -O -d longitude,100.0,290.0 -d latitude,0.0,65.0 ww3.Hs.July.nc ww3.Hs.July.NPac1.nc
$python
>>>import xarray as xr
>>>xr.open_dataarray('ww3.Hs.July.NPac1.nc')
<xarray.DataArray 'hs' (time: 31, latitude: 66, longitude: 191)>
[390786 values with dtype=float64]
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 ...
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 100.0 101.0 102.0 103.0 104.0 105.0 106.0 ...
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1993-07-01 1993-07-02 1993-07-03 ...
Attributes:
    long_name:      significant height of wind and swell waves
    standard_name:  sea_surface_wave_significant_height
    globwave_name:  significant_wave_height
    units:          m
    valid_min:      0
    valid_max:      32000
```